# Passing a vector<string> as a parameter in the parameterized constructor of an object

Tags: c++, vector

I've got an assignment that I am working on, so I am hesitant of posting all of my code on here (for the off chance that my professor somehow would find it - the policy is that would constitute as cheating).

My issue comes at this though: I've got a visual C++ program that has a textbox that takes a user inputs a string, clicks a button, and adds that string to a vector. I then need to pass that vector (full of strings) into a newly created object via its parameterized constructor. There is also some inheritance involved.

basically, in the .h file for the object and the forms .h file, I have the following (as per how the teacher wanted it to be in the object .h file that I am not allowed to change):

```
typedef vector<string> StringList;
```

I then create a new parent object and a new vector in the form's .h file:

```
private: Trial * t;
private: StringList * strings;
```

then initialize it in the form's constructor:

```
strings = new StringList;
```

I then try to create a new instance of a derived class and assign it on the parent object, while passing the required parameters:

```
t = new Vector_Trial( strings, multi, type );
```

I get a red line underneath the first parenthesis that says:

```
Error: no instance of constructor "Vector_Trial::Vector_Trial" matches the argument list
argument types are:(StringList *, int, Trial::TrialType)
```

The following are the constructors for the parent class and the derived class:

```
Trial ( StringList & s, int num_runs, TrialType t )
      : strings(s), numRuns(num_runs), type(t) { }

Vector_Trial ( StringList & s, int num_runs, TrialType t ) : Trial ( s, num_runs, t ) {}
```

I'm assuming my issue is with the vector.. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just declare the private member as "StringList strings" instead, and just ditch the call to `new`?

Comment: Just use `StringList strings`, not using the pointer version, then in the `Vector_Trial` constructor you can call swap method on the input `StringList` to swap the strings in.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I do that, I get the error: Error: A member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type

Comment: I appears that you need to create Vector_Trial as an 'unmanaged class' and then wrap in in a 'managed' class via a pointer (pimpl). Personally I would avoid using a .NET compiler which adds this sort of nonsense to C++. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11588261/unmanaged-var-as-member-of-managed-class-c

Answer (score 0):

If you use this function,

```
Vector_Trial ( StringList & s, int num_runs, TrialType t )
```

You will pass to it a `StringList` object, not a pointer to `StringList`.
Should you change your `strings` declaration as below,

```
private: StringList strings;
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: 

Error: A member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to make `strings` a `StringList*`.

Instead, just declare it as `StringList strings;`, and remove the call to `new`.

Comment: When I do that, I get the error: Error: A member of a managed class cannot be of a non-managed class type

Comment: @user3089335 : Ahh, you're programming in C++/CLI?  That's a different language...  I'm not sure how to best help you.  You could try something ugly like passing `*strings` as an argument to `Vector_Trial` as a hack, but... ew?